# Bindings within ng-repeat in nested components not binding properly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a hierarchical set of AngularJS components which represent a table, its rows and the cells in each row.

I've created a table class object which has a collection of rows, and a row class which has a collection of cells, and a cell object.  References to these object are associated with the components which display them on the page.

My problem is I cant get the row class instance to bind properly to the row component.  The rows are created properly and accessible in the table component.  I use ng-repeat to iterate the rows collection so I can bind the row instance (DetailRow) to the each row component (detail-row), but although I can access the each row object inside the ng-repeat, and I cant seem to pass the DetailRow instance to the rowitem attribute the detail-row component binds to.     I tried both `<detail-row rowitem="myRow">` as well as `<detail-row rowitem="$ctrl.myRow">` but neither work.

HTML Templates for components and component definitions and controllers are below:

```
var budgetDetailsTemplate= `
    <div id="details-table"> 
      <div id="budget-details-header">             
        <div class="back-link">Budget Changes</div>
        <div class="name">>  {{$ctrl.account.name.trim()}}</div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div id="budget" class="cell">   
          <div class="cell-header">Current Budget:</div>
          <div class="cell-content">{{$ctrl.formatCurrency($ctrl.account.budget)}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="changes" class="cell">   
          <div class="cell-header">Changes:</div>
          <div class="cell-content">{{$ctrl.formatCurrency($ctrl.changes)}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="changes" class="cell">   
          <div class="cell-header">New Budget</div>
          <div class="cell-content">{{$ctrl.formatCurrency($ctrl.changes)}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div><detail-table account="$ctrl.account"></detail-table></div>
`;

var detailTableTemplate = `
    <div>Name: {{account.name}}</div>
    <div id="detail-rows">
      <div id="detail-table">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="myRow in $ctrl.tableRows()">
          <div>test:  {{myRow.guid}}</div>   [<---This works as expected]
          <detail-row rowitem="myRow"></detail-row> [<---this doesnt pass to the controller]
        </div>     
      </div>
    </div>
`;
```

```
var detailRowTemplate = `
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(DESC)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(QUANT)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(UNITS)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(RATE)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(SUBT)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(X)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(TAXR)"></detail-cell>
    <detail-cell cell="$ctrl.getCell(TOT)"></detail-cell>
`;

var detailCellTemplate= `
    <span class="detail-cell" id="{{$ctrl.guid}}">{{$ctrl.cellContents()}}</span>
`;
```

controllers & component definitions:

```
function budgetDetailsPageController($scope, $timeout, $rootScope, $http, $window, $uibModal) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.account = this.account;
    ctrl.changes = 150;
    ctrl.test = function() {

        alertMessage("budget details controller:  account: " + ctrl.account.name);
    };
    ctrl.formatCurrency = function(value) {
        return formatCurrency(value);
    }
}

app.component("budgetDetails", {
    template: budgetDetailsTemplate,
    controller: budgetDetailsPageController,
    bindings: {
        account: '='
    }
});
```

```
function detailTableController($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl=this;
    ctrl.foo = "I am detailTableController";
    ctrl.table = new BudgetDetails();
    ctrl.account = this.account;
    ctrl.currentRow = ctrl.table.appendRow();
    ctrl.table.appendRow();
    ctrl.tableRows =  function () {
        return ctrl.table.getRows();
    };
    ctrl.rowCount = ctrl.table.count;
}

app.component("detailTable",  {
    template: detailTableTemplate,
    controller: detailTableController,
    bindings: {
        account: '='
    }
});
```

```
function detailRowController($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl=this;   
    ctrl.foo = "I am detailRowController";
    ctrl.myRow = this.rowitem;
    if (ctrl.myRow===undefined) {
        console.log("myRow is undefined");
    }

    ctrl.getCell = function(index) {
       return ctrl.myRow.getCell(index);
    }
}

app.component("detailRow",  {
    template: detailRowTemplate,
    controller: detailRowController,
    bindings: {
        rowitem: '='
    }
});
```

```
function detailCellController($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl=this;
    ctrl.cell=this.cell;
    if (ctrl.cell===undefined) {
        console.log("cell is undefined");
    }

    ctrl.cellContents = function() {
        if (ctrl.cell) {
            return cell.valueString;
        } else {
            return "undefined cell";
        }
    }    
}

app.component("detailCell",  {
    template: detailCellTemplate,
    controller: detailCellController,
    bindings: {
        cell: '='
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More fooling around with this and I discovered that bindings when the component runs the controller code for the first time.  This means you need to wait until the component is ready and the bindings are populated before you can attempt to do anything with a bound object, l (Otherwise the bound object will be undefined).  $onInit is the answer to this particular timing problem.

So for example,if I want to create a new variable containing the bound object `ctrl.myRow = this.rowitem;` in my controller function, I need instead to:

```
ctrl.$onInit = function() { 
   ctrl.myRow = this.rowitem;
}
```